# jQuery removing elements with incremented Ids

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove elements and their wrappers from a page on a button press, but I need the remaining ids to be renumbered in order.

The problem is that I need them to have an incremental Id (eg Parent[0], Parent[1]) so that they can be bound to a ASP.net MVC model when the form is submitted.

### Here is a sample of coding I'm testing on:

```
<div class="row" id="grandparent[0]">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="parent[0]">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input value="zero" disabled id="[0]" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-warning">[0]</button>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row" id="grandparent[1]">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="parent[1]">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input value="one" disabled id="[1]" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-warning">[1]</button>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="row" id="grandparent[2]">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="parent[2]">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input value="two" disabled id="[2]" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-warning">[2]</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I have attempted to use the value in the button (as a simple test, which will later be replaced using a better way), then locate the grandparent wrapper (ie`<div class="row" id="grandparent[1]">`), then store the html() in a variable and replace [1] with a [0]. Then I would be removing the previous parent (eg `<div class="col-md-12" id="parent[1]">..</div>`) and replacing it with this new one.

However, the above does not work as it only carries out the replace on the first line (ie `<div class="col-md-12" id="parent[0]">`).

I am wondering if this is the best road in tackling this problem, or if anyone has any better suggestions. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about using class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is pretty straightforward. You want to:

1. Remove the wrapper (the `.row` ancestor of your delete button) when the delete button is clicked.
2. Find all the rows left in your form.
3. Iterate through them and rename all the elements whose ids or attributes need to be renamed.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PRXcF/)

```
var $form = $('#myForm');

$form.on('click', '.btn-warning', function (event) {
    var $item = $(event.currentTarget);
    var $wrapper = $item.closest('.row');

    $wrapper.hide('fast', function () {
        $wrapper.remove();

        // Find all the items you need to renumber
        var $rows = $form.find('.row');

        // Iterate through them
        $rows.each(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row);

            // Do whatever renaming you need to do
            $row.attr('id', 'grandparent[' + i + ']');
            $row.children().attr('id', 'parent[' + i + ']');
            $row.find('input')
                .attr('id', '[' + i + ']')
                .val(getNumberWord(i));
            $row.find('button').text('[' + i + ']');
        });

    });

    event.preventDefault();
});

// I added this part just to be silly, really
function getNumberWord(i) {
    var words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
    return words[i];
}
```

Comment: Dang!  I had this sitting in jsfiddle and thought it would be safe to take my morning walk before posting!  This is the correct answer though so I won't post a duplicate answer.  +1!

Comment: D'oh! I guess it's never safe to take your morning walk. Sorry for beating you to the punch, mate.

Comment: I had something similar (http://jsfiddle.net/59nbe/).  Yours is prettier, but I noticed that it's not necessary to replace all IDs--only those after the removed element.

Comment: @psquared That's a nice optimization.

Comment: @psquared, Impressive :)